# Facebook api not returning friends contact info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hello.js

In my contacts manager app, I need to have an option to import contacts from facebook.  Im using `hello.js`  This is the function

```
    function getFriends(network, path){

    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    list.innerHTML = '';


    // login
    hello.login( network, {scope:'friends'}, function(auth){
    if(!auth||auth.error){
        console.log("Signin aborted");
        return;
    }
    // Get the friends
    // using path, me/friends or me/contacts
    hello( network ).api( path , function responseHandler(r){
        for(var i=0;i<r.data.length;i++){
            var o = r.data[i];
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var ph = "";
            if(o.gd$phoneNumber != undefined)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j <= o.gd$phoneNumber.length; j++   ) {
                    if(o.gd$phoneNumber[j] != undefined)
                    {
                        //console.log(o.gd$phoneNumber[j].$t);
                        ph += o.gd$phoneNumber[j].$t +'<br>';
                    }

                };
            }
            li.innerHTML = o.name + (o.thumbnail?" <img src="+o.thumbnail+" />":'') +' Phone : '+ph;
            list.appendChild(li);
        };


    });
});
```

}

The function is invoked by `getFriends('facebook','me/friends')` .This only returns the count of friends like this

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 1076
   }
}
```

but by using `getFriends('facebook','me/taggable_friends')`, I'm getting the name and image of the friends but not any email id or contact number.

Can anyone figure out the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

`/me/taggable_friends` is ONLY for getting tagging tokens (you don´t get User IDs), and ONLY for tagging your friends (in status posts, for example).

`/me/friends` only returns friends who authorized your App too, that´s intentional. Users who don´t use your App don´t show up for privacy reasons.

That being said, even if you would be able to get ALL friends, you can´t get any details like email and especially not a contact number. You can´t even get the phone number from the authorized User.

Detailed information can be found in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: if the user sets his email and phone number public, even then we can't get them ?

Comment: no, even then it´s not possible. public does not always mean you can grab it with the api. email is only possible for authorized users (with the email scope), phone is not possible at all.

Comment: all those existing apps are using v1.0, they will stop working after april 2015